# PHPDoc or type hint class as parameter to method

Tags: php, phpdoc, type-hinting

How can I indicate that a function/method accepts a class as a parameter? Either PHPDoc or type hinting would be sufficient, but neither seems to allow it.

Here's an example of what I'm thinking should work...

```php
/**
 * @param $class class  A reference to a class that will be used to do something
 */
function doReallyWeirdStuff(class $class){
  $class::callStaticMethod();
}
```

I'm already aware of how to pass the class to this function. How do I indicate that you *should* do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class names are merely strings, thus you must type hint them as string. You then need to check it's actually a class, at run-time, in your method:

```
/**
 * @param $class string  A reference to a class that will be used to do something
 */
function doReallyWeirdStuff(string $class){
  if (class_exists($class)) {
    $class::callStaticMethod();
  } else {
    throw \InvalidArgumentException;
  }
}
```

Note that, to enable strict adherence to string values (as would be required for class names), you need to enable strict type hinting:

```
declare(strict_types=1);
```

Otherwise, you could conceivably call like so:

```
doReallyWeirdStuff(M_PI);
```

which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Aha! Fantastic! Thank you

Comment: To pass in the class name you should use `\MyNamespace\MyClass::class` so that your IDE can refactor that code.

Comment: I will as soon as the waiting period expires. :)

Comment: `declare(strict_types=1)` is not required to enable scalar type hints. It is only required if you want PHP to throw an error if the exact type is not respected within the file (by default, PHP will convert another type to the type hinted, not throw an error)

Comment: You're likely right about the OP. Just stating an inaccuracy because lots of people other than the OP may come across your solution and take your words literally.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with PHPDoc type hinting, unless you pass an actual object instance.

You can however abuse the PHP Doc type hinting.

```
string|Class $class
or
Class $class
```

This will produce very mixed results depending on what you're running. You'll lose some of the ability to run type checking without false negatives/positives.